# Interactive Debugging in R

Tags: r, debugging, rscript

I have a toy R script (test.R) as follows:

```
myString <- "Hello World"
browser()
print(myString)
```

I want to interactively debug the script, hence the '`browser()`' call.

However, when I run the script like this:

```
Rscript test.R
```

I just see:

```
Called from: top level 
[1] "Hello World"
```

i.e. the 'browser()' call seems to get skipped. When I run the script like this:

```
R -f test.R
```

I see:

```
>
> myString <- "Hello World"
> browser()
Called from: top level
Browse[1]> print (myString)
[1] "Hello World"
Browse[1]>
>
```

But, execution does not stop at 'Browse[1]>' to allow me to debug.

What am I missing here? In python, I can insert "`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`" to debug. I am looking for something similar in R.

Comment: I would suggest running your script line by line the console or in R studio

Comment: I am working with a huge set of scripts, e.g. script A calls script B calls script C calls script D, etc. How would you suggest debugging a problem in D? I can only call D from A. My usual approach is to set a breakpoint in D and then kick off A, but it seems that can't be done here. Thanks for your pointer :)

Comment: Here is an intro to debugging with Rstudio.  It might provide a start: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200713843-Debugging-with-RStudio

Answer (score 0):

[See this](https://rstats.wtf/debugging-r-code.html#browser) for how to use `browser()`. You will be able to `source('scriptname.R')` a script in the R interactive environment on terminal (by running `R` instead of `Rscript scriptname.R`) and then `browser()` will behave very similar to `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` . The one major caveat is arguments - you could manually configure that to use the arguments you would supply on the command line by using say `if(interactive())` (or there might be other ways to achieve this).

Comment: This is a partial solution which helps especially if your code lives on server and you can't use Rstudio server (that's paid).

Comment: This doesn't need Rstudio to work. In your terminal run R (instead of Rscript) to get an interactive R session on your terminal. Then source your code at the R prompt (>, as @piedpiper says above). The code will stop running at your browser() command and become an interactive terminal session (like pdb in python).